# PhantomJS error

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

`error: Could not spawn 
 [/root/AgarioBotsV3/node_modules/phantomjsprebuilt/lib/phantom\bin\phantomjs.exe
    ] executable. Please make sure phantomjs is installed correctly.
    error:  Error: spawn /root/AgarioBotsV3/node_modules/phantomjs-
    prebuilt/lib/phantom\bin\phantomjs.exe ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1016:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:189:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:366:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:102:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:161:9)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:607:11)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:575:3`
    i dont know how to fix please help. Im using linux ubuntu 16.04 server

Comment: `Please make sure phantomjs is installed correctly.` If you don't have it installed, run `npm install -g phantomjs-prebuilt`

Comment: Thank you Chris Lam. It worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Please make sure phantomjs is installed correctly.`

If you don't have it installed, run `npm install -g phantomjs-prebuilt`

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have a .dockerignore file.. an inside this a line 
node_modules

Answer (score 0):

I came to this question in March 2021 and had the same issue dockerizing highcharts: it worked on my machine but failed on docker run. In the end, the solution was to find a FROM node version that worked. This Dockerfile works using the latest Node docker image and almost latest highcharts npm version (always pick up specific npm versions):

```
FROM node:15.12.0

ENV ACCEPT_HIGHCHARTS_LICENSE YES

# see available versions of highcharts at https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-export-server
RUN npm install highcharts-export-server@2.0.30 -g

EXPOSE 7801

# run the container using: docker run -p 7801:7801 -t CONTAINER_TAG
CMD [ "highcharts-export-server", "--enableServer", "1" ]
```